# How can I add, subtract, or multiply two variables using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title> test ! </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
</head>
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">

first number : <input class="form-control" id="num1" />
<br>
second number : <input class="form-control" id="num2" />
<br>
<select id="mathtype">
   <option value="add"> addition </option>
   <option value="sub"> subtraction </option>
   <option value="mul"> multiplication </option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()" > submit </button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="output" >

</div>



</body>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>

function submit(){

    var mathtype = document.getElementById['mathtype'];

    if (mathtype == add ) {
        return num1 + num2;
    } else if (mathtype == sub ) {
        return num1 - num2;
    } else if (mathtype == mul ) {
        return num1 * num2;
    }   

    return true;

}

</script>

</html>
```

My current error:

> SyntaxError: function statement requires a name.

I'd like to make a program that will execute a math operation according to the selected value (add,sub,mul), and after clicking submit, the answer is shown in the input with an id "output".

Comment: Remember that you should be asking with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, most of the HTML is not required.

Comment: sorry sir josecortes hehe since im new in javascript im assuming the declaring js script might one of the problem hehe

Comment: No need to apologize. We all are here to learn and help

Answer (score 2):

```js
function submit() {
  var mathtype = document.getElementById('mathtype').value;
  //Get the value of the select element..Correct the typo([])
  var num1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  //Get the value of `num1` input and convert it to type `Number`
  var num2 = Number(document.getElementById('num2').value);
  //Get the value of `num2` input and convert it to type `Number`
  if (mathtype == 'add') {
    //Compare with `string` as value of select input will be of type string, you did not have variable `add` to be tested
    document.getElementById('output').value = num1 + num2;
  } else if (mathtype == 'sub') {
    //Compare with `string` as value of select input will be of type string, you did not have variable `sub` to be tested
    document.getElementById('output').value = num1 - num2;
  } else if (mathtype == 'mul') {
    //Compare with `string` as value of select input will be of type string, you did not have variable `mul` to be tested
    document.getElementById('output').value = num1 * num2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  first number :
  <input class="form-control" id="num1" />
  <br>second number :
  <input class="form-control" id="num2" />
  <br>
  <select id="mathtype">
    <option value="add">addition</option>
    <option value="sub">subtraction</option>
    <option value="mul">multiplication</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()">submit</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="output">
</div>
```

***Note***: Go through the comments for detailed explaination

Comment: @expert123, Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__